# How to control browser refresh in Flutter Web

Tags: bloc, flutter-web

I write a flutter web sample app that uses bloc as many samples on the internet.
Imagine a simple flutter project with the bloc to the login user. Get a username and pass and pass to bloc and UI automatically show home page now the problem is: this is web project after login when the user refreshes the browser login page popup again.
How to manage to load the main page even after the page refresh?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62237262/flutter-web-detect-browser-tab-close-or-refresh

Comment: @hiashutoshsingh I'm not sure that this is allowed: https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/avoid_web_libraries_in_flutter.html

Any other solutions guys??

Answer (score 0):

I use `localStorage` with a token cached. Refreshing a page on a web is basically re-rendering all resources(maybe that's why Flutter Web only supports `hot restart` but not `hot reload`).
For me, when I need to check login status or user data, I use a cached token(in case I use server), or a Firebase auth listener(if I use Firebase) before showing any UI.

Answer (score -3):

I make it work with State Management
there are many solutions for state management
I use Change Notifier State management