# Flutter Web: Detect browser/tab close or refresh?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

With Flutter Android and iOS modules you can use AppLifeCycleState to detect when the app is put into the background.

Is there something similar for Flutter Web where I can detect the browser/tab closing or refreshing?

I essentially want to run a Firestore command if the person closes their browser or refreshes.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the function "onBeforeUnload" to check if the tab is being closed. It might detect page refresh also.

```
import 'dart:html' as html;
html.window.onBeforeUnload.listen((event) async{
  // do something
});
```

or

```
import 'dart:html' as html;
html.window.onUnload.listen((event) async{
  // do something
});
```

Comment: Would this interfere with my Android/iOS modules? I have read in the past that dart:html import causes crashes on mobile devices.

Comment: @RossPatterson you can use https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html work in android/iOS

Comment: @Rinkesh the package you are telling does not supported on Flutter web.

Comment: How can we show a confirm dialog for the user that "You really want to close the tab"?

Comment: @MuhammadUllah I'm pretty sure that it has to be something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311341/confirmation-before-closing-of-tab-browser).

Comment: How do I make onBeforeUnload not get triggered when the page refreshes? Right not it is being called both during page refresh as well as during page close. Also the behaviour is inconsistent. Meaning, sometimes it doesn't call my function at the time of page/tab close.

Answer (score 3):

Just use OnBeforeUnload or OnUnload.
to me it worked without async, I recon it is because the window doesn't wait to be closed it just closes.
if you want to change something in your db when the user exits tab or refreshes, you should call a method on the back thread so that it will keep on running and finish the task even after window closed/tab closed/refresh.

```
html.window.onBeforeUnload.listen((event) {
   // change something in db
});
```

Comment: how can you run something on the back thread?